# How to make json array name series name, array data -series data in highcharts?

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am getting the array list encoded with json:

```
 [{"root":[0,0,0,0,0,75,75,100,0,0]}, {"aleks":[2,0,2,1,2,3,4,0,23,12,40]} ...more]
```

from my php file.

And would like to show it in my column based highcharts like this:

Each column series to be named with array names, root, aleks and etc. 
And data series to be their datas.

I have tried this code to feed series:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "p_result.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){

            for(var i in data){
                      options.series[i].name = i;
                      options.series[i].data = data[i];
                }
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

But I am getting wrong results, well, datas are not shown.

Any helps will appreciated.

Comment: As a result how your options.series looks like?

Comment: I am getting i = 0, and data[i] to be [object Object], any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for(var i in data)` is iterating the outer json array and not each object inside the array.

Try:

```
for(var i in data){ // iterate outer array
    for(var j in data[i]){ // iterate inner objects properties
        options.series[i].name = j; // this is the key
        options.series[i].data = data[i][j]; // use the key and index to get value
        break; // we only care about the first object
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W93HY/).

Comment: Once more question. When I have two or more, the option.series is giving me error "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined". How should I define it properly? Thanks.

Comment: I had assumed you were reusing old series objects.  Just push them as you go see update here: http://jsfiddle.net/W93HY/1/

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking to rewrite using addseries method. But the solution is working perfectly. Thanks.